# CSRF token still giving error after having middleware, html tag and csrf_protect

Tags: django, csrf, django-csrf, csrf-token

I'm trying to get the view to redirect the user to the index page if they type in a page that does not exist. After rendering the 404 error and pressing the button, the 403 CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. comes up.

I've checked and the middleware was installed in settings.py, I routed the URLs correctly(probably), added {% csrf_token %} in the HTML, and also added @csrf_protect for the view.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

```
def title(request, title):
    entry = util.get_entry(title)
    if entry == None:
        code = '404'
        message = 'Page not found'
        return render(request,'encyclopedia/error.html',{
            'message': message,
            'code': code
        })
    elif entry != None:
        return HttpResponse(title)

@csrf_protect
def redirect_to_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return redirect('/')

    return render(request, 'error/')
```

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Errors
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1>{{ code }} {{ message }}</h1>

<form action="{% url 'redirect' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Redirect</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Help
The reason was given for failure:

    Origin checking failed - https://acpanda1408-code50-103527608-pjqw44gw727jvj-8000.preview.app.github.dev does not match any trusted origins.
    
In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django’s CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:

Your browser is accepting cookies.
The view function passes a request to the template’s render method.
In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.
If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.
The form has a valid CSRF token. After logging in in another browser tab or hitting the back button after a login, you may need to reload the page with the form, because the token is rotated after a login.
You’re seeing the help section of this page because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and only the initial error message will be displayed.

You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.
```

Comment: `Origin checking failed` usually has something to do with Trusted origins..
are you posting the form from a different URL?- if so, you should look into:
[CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#csrf-trusted-origins) + 

If you are using 4.0+ you've got to put the entire scheme `https://` and all.